# Vue router missing params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to use router link to pass a parameter to a page. The issue is that I'm not able to access the param playerId in the players page. I've followed the example in [vue router site](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html). Below are my code.

**Route.js**

```
{
      path: '/player/:slug',
      name: 'playerprofile',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "playerprofile" */ './views/PlayerProfile.vue'),
      props: true
    }
```

**Router Link Tag**

```
<router-link :to="{path: '/player/'+ player.personName.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase(), params: {slug: player.personName,playerId: player.personId}}">
            <TextH3 class="font-bold flex-1 text-black hover:text-primary">{{ player.personName }}</TextH3>
          </router-link>
```

**Before Route** hook in the page

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        console.log(to)
        next()
    }
```

**Console Log**

```
fullPath: "/player/test-data"
hash: ""
matched: [{…}]
meta: {}
name: "playerprofile"
params:
  slug: "Test Data"
__proto__: Object
path: "/player/test-data"
query: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `path` yours `params` will be equals to your `slug` in your case will be `"slug: test-data"`, there you should use `query`.

If you want pass `params` you should use `name` instead of `path` as [your link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) says.

**update**: This hack should work for you:

```
<router-link
  :to="{
    name: 'playerprofile',
    params: {
      slug: player.personName.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase(),
      playerName: player.personName,
      playerId: player.personId
    }
  }"
>
  <TextH3 class="font-bold flex-1 text-black hover:text-primary">
    {{ player.personName }}
  </TextH3>
</router-link>
```

Then u can access to params **playerName** & **playerId**.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help for you :

```
created() {
    console.log(this.$route);
    this.slug = this.$router.params.slug;
  },
```